# Oracle Index not being used when joining to another table

Tags: sql, oracle10g, indexing

I have the following sql being run on an Oracle 10g database:

```
select  /*+ ALL_ROWS */
       to_number(cv.old_value) as cv_id,
       to_number(job.old_value) as job_id
  from amendments,
       amnddets cv,
       amnddets job
 where amendments.table_name = 'TIMESHEET_LAYER'
   and amendments.dml_type = 'D'
   and cv.amnd_id = amendments.amnd_id 
   and cv.column_name = 'CV_ID'
   and job.amnd_id = amendments.amnd_id
   and job.column_name = 'JOB_ID';
```

There are the following indexes that have been created:

```
create index amendments_dmp_type_upper on amendments upper(dmp_type);
create index amendments_table_name_upper on amendments upper(table_name);
create index amendments_pk on amendments (amnd_id);
create index amended_column_name_idx on amnddets (column_name);
create index amnddets_amnd_id_idx on amnddets (amnd_id);
```

I have also tried using ANSI joins (the below sql) but this does not use the indexes either, placing `upper()` around the `table_name` and `dml_type` also has no affect.

The above query is taking approximately 30 - 40 secs to retrieve around 2500 rows.

I looked at the explain plan and can't see that the index on `amendments` for `table_name` and `dml_type` are being used.

[image: Explain plain for oracle joins attached]

Below is the ANSI explain plan for:

```
select  /*+ ALL_ROWS */
       to_number(cv.old_value) as cv_id,
       to_number(job.old_value) as job_id
  from amendments
  JOIN amnddets cv on cv.amnd_id = amendments.amnd_id and cv.column_name = 'CV_ID'
  JOIN amnddets job on job.amnd_id = amendments.amnd_id and job.column_name = 'JOB_ID'
 where upper(amendments.table_name) = 'TIMESHEET_LAYER'
   and amendments.dml_type = 'D';
```

[image: Explain plan for the ANSI joins]

Could any one advise why the `table_name`, `dml_type` and `column_name` indexes aren't being used in the above query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have actually run this as you say:

```
create index amendments_dmp_type_upper on amendments upper(dmp_type);
```

then what you have actually created is an index on `amendments(dmp_type)` without the `upper` function!

The correct syntax is:

```
create index amendments_dmp_type_upper on amendments (upper(dmp_type));
```

Perhaps surprisingly, your statement works but the word "upper" is treated as a table alias - this works too:

```
create index amendments_dmp_type_upper on amendments foo(dmp_type);
```

Comment: Cheers, for the help with the above suggestions.  The above amendments to the indexes really improved performance.  The query ran in 0.02sec rather than 30 - 40 secs.  I added the function `upper()` indexes on the `dml_type`,`table_name` and `column_name`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert on Oracle, but it appears that it's not using (or unable to use) INDEX Merging.  This means you need composite indexes.

```
create index amnddets_column_name_amnd_id_idx on amnddets (column_name, amnd_id);

create index amendments_dml_type_table_name_amnd_id_idx on amendments (dml_type, table_name, amnd_id)
```